# issue with mysql query 'where' priority

Tags: mysql

Im having issues with this mysql query, i need it to bring ONLY the files that have the condition  `WHERE` st`.class_id in ('%s')` as principal, and the other conditions as secundary, tried changing the or's to and's with no luck,
thanks in advance.

```
$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT `st`.id,`st`.sub_name,`st`.stime,`st`.edate FROM {$_tables['subject']} AS st WHERE `st`.class_id in ('%s') and (`stime` BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s') OR (`edate` BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s');",[$start,$end,$start,$end, $value]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) of `AND` versus `OR`.

You have a boolean expression in your WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE A AND B OR C
```

Since `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, it is evaluated as if you had done this:

```
WHERE (A AND B) OR C
```

That's probably the source of your problem.

To override this, you need to use parentheses explicitly:

```
WHERE A AND (B OR C)
```